# Compare names of files in two directories in command-line

Tags: command-line, bash, console

Is it possible to compare names of files in two directories?

I need to get information about how many similar and how many different names of files  in directory `some_directory` and `other_directory`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 diff -q some_directory other_directory
```

It will list the differences between the directories with lines like this:

```
Files some_directory/ttt.pdf and other_directory/ttt.pdf differ
Only in other_directory xxxxx.pdf
Only in some_directory xxxTxx.pdf
```

If you also want to see the actual differences omit the "-q". If you only want to know what files are missing or different and also want to include subdirectories do ...

```
diff -qr some_directory other_directory
```

Answer (score 1):

```
diff -qr dir1 dir2 | sort
```

That will compare files in two directories.

If you remove the `q` argument and the `|` symbol it will show all the files in two directories